# OData query to get a field values by column position in the list

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, rest, query, odata

So I want an OData query that allows me to get the field and its values by position in the viewable list.
[image]

In the above picture, for example, I want the values in the "Title" column but that column can change to let's say to the "ID" column position wise. I would need my query to be to stay the same.

I know how to target specific columns by specific column name but I'm not quite sure by view position. I've looked and have come empty-handed. Is it even possible? Any advice is appreciated. :)

Comment: Is this only for public views, or do you need it to work for personal views too?

Comment: Actually, a better question might be - how is it that you know the column position in the view but you don't know what field that is?

Comment: Why do you need the position of the colum?

Comment: @Ariser It was so I can import custom styling to a popover I made for the column. No worries though guys I figured out my issue. I ended up just grabbing the <tr> from the page itself.